# Extract Dictionary Object from another Object

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I have a data model configured

```
Public Partial Class card
    <JsonProperty("faction")>
    Public Property Faction As Exile
    <JsonProperty("id")>
    Public Property Id As String
    <JsonProperty("image")>
    Public Property Image As String
    <JsonProperty("import_id")>
    Public Property ImportId As String
    <JsonProperty("kredits")>
    Public Property Kredits As Long
    <JsonProperty("rarity")>
    Public Property Rarity As Rarity
    <JsonProperty("set")>
    Public Property [Set] As [Set]
    <JsonProperty("text")>
    Public Property Text As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    <JsonProperty("title")>
    Public Property Title As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    <JsonProperty("type")>
    Public Property Type As TypeEnum
    <JsonProperty("can_create", NullValueHandling:=NullValueHandling.Ignore)>
    Public Property CanCreate As String()
    <JsonProperty("exile", NullValueHandling:=NullValueHandling.Ignore)>
    Public Property Exile As Exile?
    <JsonProperty("attack", NullValueHandling:=NullValueHandling.Ignore)>
    Public Property Attack As Long?
    <JsonProperty("defense", NullValueHandling:=NullValueHandling.Ignore)>
    Public Property Defense As Long?
    <JsonProperty("operationCost", NullValueHandling:=NullValueHandling.Ignore)>
    Public Property OperationCost As Long?
    <JsonProperty("attributes", NullValueHandling:=NullValueHandling.Ignore)>
    Public Property Attributes As Attribute()
End Class
```

I wish to pull all the values that are in the `Title` Dictionary so basically I have the full keyvaluepairs listing in a separate dictionarylist from the object itself.

I figured I could just `For Each` through the entire object and add them to a new dictonarylist but there must be a cleaner/quicker method for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Dictionary constructor which takes another dictionary

```vb
Dim myCard As card
' deserialize to mycard
Dim myTitle As New Dictionary(Of String, String)(myCard.Title)
```